# Kubernetes ошибка при pull из локального registry: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: реестр, kubernetes, certificate

Kubernetes развернут из kubeadm без установки docker - используется containerd со сгенерированной по-умолчанию конфигурацией. Подготовлен тестовый image который находится на отдельном сервере с адресом типа https://my-reg:5000. При подключении через docker авторизация работает (сертификат ложу в директорию типа /etc/docker/certs.d/my-reg:5000), pull-push работает. Секрет для авторизации создал как описано в документации Kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry. Но на этапе создания тестового пода возникает ошибка x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. У меня простая конфигурация с одной worker нодой. Куда мне положить сертификат и как его указать Kubernetes чтобы нода понимала, где лежит сертификат? Все что я прописал по документации container.d https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md не работает (skip_verify = true либо указание сертификата для хоста https://my-reg:5000)